# Beans definition in beans.xml file

Tags: quarkus

Is it possible to define beans in beans.xml file?

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0">
<bean id="example" class="example" scope="singleton"/>
```

I'm trying this but i get a NullPointerException when i try to use that bean.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the XML schema that you yourself declare (http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd), you will see that it *doesn't* allow a `<bean>` element. So no, defining beans in `beans.xml` is not possible in CDI.

Moreover, as far as I know, ArC (the "CDI" implementation in Quarkus, which isn't fully CDI compliant) completely ignores the content of `beans.xml`, it merely looks for its presence.

Quarkus CDI guide itself (for Quarkus version 0.21.1) [mentions](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#limitations) that as one of the limitations:

> beans.xml descriptor content is ignored

Currently, `beans.xml` is used only as a marker file that signifies an archive should be treated as a bean archive.